# Error when I use HttpUrlConnection to download info from a specific url

Tags: java, android

I am writing an app on android 3.1, and I am using galaxy tab 10.1 to test my app.

I wrote a function called OpenHttpConnection() in order to get some information from a specific website. And the code snippets is:

```
private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    String host = url.getHost();
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
    String ip = address.getHostAddress();
    Toast.makeText(this, "ip address: " + ip.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        Toast.makeText(this, "prepare for connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        httpConn.connect();
        Toast.makeText(this, "connecting established", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");
    }
    return in;
}
```

Error happens when the line "httpConn.connect()" is being executed. I googled this question and found many people got this problem, and they said it was a matter of DNS. Then I tried to get the ip address of this url, I failed, somethings was wrong. I have already add the permission to the AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Did I miss some permission?

I can use my tablet to access the internet successfully and the DNS of my tablet is as same as my pc, and they are in one LAN.

I am very confused, and can u help solve it?

;)thx

Comment: Please describe the error (check Logcat)

Comment: post url  which you are passing in OpenHttpConnection or Logcat

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing this recently so I can probably tell you that there are 2 possible issues:

1. You need to make sure you are doing this on a background thread using either `Handler` or an `AsyncTask`.
2. If you must do it in your UI thread, you need to turn off [`Strict mode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder.html).

Check out this great [tutorial in running background threads in android](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#concurrency), the AyncTask section of the tutorial actually downloads a webpage so is very relevant. I tried it recently and it works.

Comment: thx for your answer, but I don't think it is helpful for me. My problem is that the app cannot use the DNS to get right IP address. And I copy this code and operation from a book called Beginning Android Tablet Application Development, it doesn't mention the Handler or AsyncTask. Thx very much anyhow.

Comment: You need to post the error you get from LogCat in order for more detailed help. However I still suspect it may have to do with `StrictMode`. I don't know what posts you have see, but they may have been referring to turning on `MultiCast` for WIFI which would mean they have more to do with `mDN`S and not `DNS` in which case there is a permission called `CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE`.

Comment: Oh, you are right, the app execute successfully after I turn off Strict mode. Thx a lot, and apologize for my haste.